# Simple Java Bank Atm login looping error

Tags: java, bank

First time posting, and people here seem helpful.
I'm currently coding my 2nd assignment of a simple bank atm/account. My login code for the users pin is not doing the following.

**1. Returning back to the start of the loop when the pin is not found in the array**

**2. making the program stop if the pin is incorrect**

Here is the snippet of the login script, only. The problem lies in the `while (menuChoice==1){}` loop.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean userLogin = false;          //Flag for user login authorization 
    boolean progOn=true;            //confirmation that program is still be running         

    int num = 0, i = 0;
    int Bal[] = {500, 250, 400, 700};
    String Names[] = {"Niall", "Sean", "John", "Connor"};
    String pin[] = {"1234", "2345", "3456", "4567"};
    String menu2 = "\n1. Deposit \n2. Withdrawal \n3. Balance \n4: Change pin \n5: Exit";
    String pinChoice = "", pinChange="";

    int sub = 0;            //To keep the subscript
    String startMenu = "";      //The entered choice for the Start menu as a string
    int menuChoice = 0;     //The entered choice for the menu as an int

    //--------------------
    //login script
    //--------------------
    while (progOn == true) {
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome! Please select an option...\n");
        System.out.println(">1. Login");
        System.out.println(">2. Quit");
        System.out.println("------------------------");

        startMenu = in.next();

        while (!startMenu.matches("[1-2]")) {       //If the user enters a non digit, give message and return
            System.out.println("\nError. Please enter a valid Menu option.\n");
            System.out.println(">1. Login");
            System.out.println(">2. Quit");

            System.out.print("Please select an option\n");          //Ask the user to choose again
            startMenu = in.next();
        }//end while loop

        menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(startMenu);   //Parse the string to an int

        while (menuChoice == 1) {           //While loop to carry out the users choice
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println("Please enter your pin number: ");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            pinChoice = in.next();

            while (!pinChoice.matches("\\d{4}")) {  // 4 numbers only message to the user, if number is shorter or longer than 4
                System.out.println("------------------------");
                System.out.println("Error, must be a 4 number pin only! Please retry:");
                System.out.println("------------------------");
                pinChoice = in.next();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
                //Check if PIN exists
                if (pinChoice.matches(pin[i])) {
                    userLogin = true;   //If the PIN exists (true) the user is brought to the main menu
                    System.out.println("------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Please select a option from the menu...");
                    sub = i;        //sub is the array number stored of that account
                }//end if PIN matches
            }


            if (userLogin == false) {   //If the PIN doesn't exist
                System.out.print("\nPin does not exist\n\n");   //Tell the user and bring them back to the main menu
            }//end if no user found

            break;

        }// end loop menuChoic == 1

        while (menuChoice == 2) {       //user chooses to Leave the program
            System.out.print("\nThank you, goodbye\n");
            System.exit(0);             //Exits the program
            break;
        }//end menuChoice==2

        //--------------------
        //end login script
        //--------------------
    }
}
```

I know the rest of the program works perfectly. I just can't get this one small part.

Bare in mind this is my first year in Comp. Sci. and my lecturer hasn't shown us any object orientating, thus he's not letting us any of it only the basics.

Thanks for looking! :)

Comment: Just to add: I would suggest that look into switch case loop. It is more often used to do "menu" as it would makes the code much more neater and easier :)

Comment: Oh trust me i would have used it if my lecturer allowed it. He has a stupid rule that we can only use code that he has shown in class, which i might add is unethical as long as i can explain its use i should be able to use anything i want. Switch case would have made my life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

In loops, you should use local variable. You have got a global variable

```
int i;
```

Try to change **i** to **int ii** in your loop

```
 for (int ii = 0; ii < Names.length; ii++) {
   //Check if PIN exists
   if (pinChoice.matches(pin[ii])) {
       userLogin = true;   //If the PIN exists (true) the user is brought to the main menu
       System.out.println("------------------------");
       System.out.println("Please select a option from the menu...");
       sub = ii;        //sub is the array number stored of that account
   }//end if PIN matches
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Whilst i get that it should be in the for loop, it honestly doesn't change anything. Not to say i didn't change it obviously. :)

Comment: Have you changed after that each 'i' into 'ii' in this loop ?

Comment: yeah. Didn't do anything. Since this is the only instance of "i" being used used in the whole program, it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

After a good 2 hours I've figured it out and added an extra step to the login process.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean userLogin = false;          //Flag for user login authorization 
        boolean progOn=true;                //confirmation that program is still be running         

        int num=0;
        int Bal[] = {500,250,400,700};
        String Names[]={"Niall", "Chris", "John", "Connor"};
        String pin[]= {"1111","2222","3333","4444"};
        String menu2= "\n1. Deposit \n2. Withdrawal \n3. Balance \n4: Change pin \n5: Exit";
        String pinChoice = "", pinChange="", strNameChoice="", startMenu="";

        int sub=0, sub2=0;                              //To keep a subscript           
        int menuChoice=0 ;                              //The entered choice for the menu and name as an int
        int nameChoice=0;

        //--------------------
        //login script
        //--------------------

        while(progOn==true){
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println("Welcome! Please select an option...\n>1. Login\n>2. Quit");
            System.out.println("------------------------");

            startMenu=in.next();

            while(!startMenu.matches("[1-2]")){                         //If the user enters a non digit, give message and return

                System.out.println("\nError. Please enter a valid Menu option.\n>1. Login\n>2. Quit\nPlease select an option\n"); //Ask the user to choose again    
                startMenu=in.next();
            }//end while loop

            menuChoice=Integer.parseInt(startMenu);                     //Parse the string to an int

            while(userLogin==false){                                    // loop to verify that the login is correct, and a rest point.

                while(menuChoice==1){                                       //While loop to carry out the users choice

                    System.out.println("------------------------");//User name selection
                    System.out.println("Please select the number of your user name. \n1> " +Names[0]+"\n2> " +Names[1]+"\n3> " +Names[2]+"\n4> " +Names[3]);
                    System.out.println("------------------------");
                    strNameChoice=in.next();

                    while(!strNameChoice.matches("[1-4]")){                  // 4 numbers only message to the user, if number is shorter or longer than 4
                        System.out.println("------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Error, must be a one of the 4 numbers only! Please retry:");
                        System.out.println("------------------------");
                        strNameChoice=in.next();
                    }


                    nameChoice=Integer.parseInt(strNameChoice);
                    sub2=nameChoice-1;



                    System.out.println("------------------------");  //PIN ENTRY
                    System.out.print("Please enter your Pin\n");
                    pinChoice = in.next();

                    while(!pinChoice.matches("\\d+")){
                        System.out.print("\nError, digits only\n");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter your PIN\n>");
                        pinChoice = in.next();
                    }//end while PIN is non digits

                    for(int i=0;i<Names[sub2].length();i++){                            //Check if PIN exists inside the loop

                        if(pinChoice.matches(pin[sub2])){
                            userLogin = true;                           //If the PIN exists (true) the user is brought to the main menu
                            sub = sub2-1;                                   //sub is the array number stored of that account
                        }//end if PIN matches
                    }       

                    if(userLogin == false){                                 //If the PIN doesn't exist
                        System.out.print("\n------------------------");
                        System.out.print("\nPin entered is incorrect \nPlease try again \n");

                    }//end if no user found
                    break;//Tell the user and bring them back to the main menu

                }// end loop menuChoice==1

                while(menuChoice==2){                   //user chooses to Leave the program

                    System.out.print("\nThank you, goodbye\n");
                    System.exit(0);                             //Exits the program
                    break;
                }//end menuChoice==2
        }   



                //--------------------
                //end login script
                //--------------------
```

My simple mistake was that I had not put in my loop to flag whether the login was true or not, making the `break;`, for the incorrect pin, useless.

```
while(userLogin==false){                                    // loop to verify that the login is correct, and a rest point.

                while(menuChoice==1){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition is `while (menuChoice ==1)`, but within the loop the value of `menuChoice` never changes.  Therefore, the loop can never be escaped. What you will need to do is change the value of `menuChoice` or add the `break;` line in the section where the PIN does not exist so that when that logic is reached, you can exit the loop.

I think the cleanest solution would be to move your `break;` to within the if condition `userLogin == false`

Good luck!

Comment: I tried that at first but it did nothing at all, but break the loop and do nothing. After 2 hours though I figured it out that I was missing a loop to put the `while(userLogin==false){` which the break would jump back to... derp on my part. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 if (pinChoice.matches(pin[i]))
```

with

```
 if (pinChoice.equals(pin[i]))
```

To check the pinChoice is equal to arrayElement use **equals** method.

Also the iteration of the for below loop :

```
for (i = 0; i < Names.length; i++)
```

must iterate to the size of `pin` array instead `Names` length

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't work since **1:** im comparing the "Names" array to the "pin" array **2:** the "pinChoice" input is a String so that i can output errors for non-digits and pin length. THanks for your time though. :)

Comment: yeah I managed to fix it and add extra login details at the same time. Problem was that the break i had didn't have a starting point to go back too. I needed the userLogin boolean i had forgotten to place above the `while(menuChoice==1){` so i added it. Like this `while(userLogin==false){            
     while(menuChoice==1){ ` It's always the simple things. :P